# Scrapy - Spider scheduling

Tags: scrapy

I would like to schedule my spider to a given point in time. For example, I want to schedule my spider for midnight before going to bed. Is there any "easy" way, through the command line to schedule this or should I use scrapyd ?

Comment: You can use `crontab` (Linux or Unix) or `SCHTASKS` (Windows).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `crontab` command to schedule your scraping job if your spiders run on your local machine. For example, if you want to schedule your spider in order to run everyday at 23:00 :

1. type `crontab -e` on the commandline, then crontab menu is going to appear on shell
   if you have not use crontab yet. It only asks you to choose a text editor so that you will be able to adjust `cron` jobs.
2. After you determine the editor you want to use, you see the content of your `crontab` file.
3. Append your `PATH` variable to this file. (You can simply copy-paste output of `echo $PATH`)
4. Add this line to the same file :

   00 23 * * * cd /your/scrapy/project/; scrapy crawl yourspidername

For further reading : https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/

Answer (score 0):

depending on your system you could set up a cron job:
https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Cron/

you could also go with frontera or scrapinghub: https://support.scrapinghub.com/support/solutions/articles/22000200419-scheduling-periodic-jobs